# Are there places to hire windsurfing gear in New Caledonia?

Tags: rental, water-sports, new-caledonia

Having seen [videos like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=6KndwQuWa3c), I'm thinking that New Caledonia is looking like a pretty amazing place to go windsurfing! However, all the videos I've seen seem to have been done by people who brought their own gear in with them.

Are there places in New Caledonia that do windsurf rentals? Ideally somewhere on the lagoon, with fairly nice gear (not just basic beginners stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are quite a few places, but most of them only have websites in French. The magic search term is `Location de planche à voile`.

For example, Diabolo Funboard (who did the video I linked to) have a rental location on Anse Vata Beach (la plage de l'Anse Vata). [Mdplaisers.com](http://www.mdplaisirs.com/contact.html) which Mark mentioned are in a similar area, and appear to have some quite nice gear from Naish.

So, it looks like there are several places there, with a range of kit from beginners to experienced!

Answer (score 3):

The [New Caledonia Office of Tourism's website](http://www.office-tourisme.nc/en/what-to-do/61+78+79+80+81+82+83+84) has a recommendation for windsurfing:

"[Aloha](http://www.office-tourisme.nc/en/aloha)" - rates are 3000-5000cfp, and their address is Promenade Roger Laroque - Anse Vata.  Maps and contact details on the link as well.

Another [windsurfing discussion](http://www.deepfried.tv/forum/postings.cfm?ID=1956) mentioned a site [Mdplaisers.com](http://www.mdplaisirs.com/contact.html) - I've linked to their contact information.

From other sites, it sounds like there are also quite a few solo guys around the beaches that you can speak to to rent gear.  Definitely sounds like they have the full range of gear too.  Sounds fun!!!